# how is /p/ pronunced in responsibility

Tags: phonetics

In Cambridge dictionary， the pronunciation of responsibility is /rɪˌspɑːn.səˈbɪl.ə.t̬i/， but I am pretty sure p is not pronounced /p/, at least not the same way as /p/ in peach. So what is happening here?

Comment: There are two pronunciations of /p/ in English, one aspirated and the other not; *peach* and *responsibility* use different ones.